# OpenCV Face Detection breaks when I move my face too quickly

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-detection

I wrote a program to detect faces in real-time and display them. The issue is that sometimes, the code will break and I will be presented with the following error:

```
  File "Removed_For_Privacy_Issues/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame',detectedface)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

After further testing, the code only breaks when there is a sudden change in the video (like when I move my face quickly or cover the camera), anyone know why?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageDraw
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
time.sleep(3)

def FacialDetection(image):
    boxes = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, 1.1, 3)
    for (x, y, w, h) in boxes:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 0), 2)
        return image

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        detectedface = FacialDetection(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',detectedface)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This probably happens when your face is almost out of window or on the border of the window? Give some if statement before drawing rectangle. Dont let its points to be out of window

Answer (score 0):

This will solve just try and except will do the work

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageDraw
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
time.sleep(3)

def FacialDetection(image):
    boxes = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, 1.1, 3)
    for (x, y, w, h) in boxes:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 0), 2)
        return image

while(cap.isOpened()):
    try:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret==True:
            detectedface = FacialDetection(frame)
            cv2.imshow('frame',detectedface)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break
    except:
        print("face not detected")
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```